# Knockout ObservableArray in custom binding

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

Can I create an observableArray inside init block in the custom binding? 
Also, I want to use this observableArray inside update method to push some new elements.

it to loop 
For example:

```
    ko.bindingHandlers.yourBindingName = {
    init: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindings, viewModel, bindingContext) {
        var animateImageArray = ko.observableArray(["img1", "img2"]);
        ko.applyBindings(animateImageArray);
    },
    update: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindings, viewModel, bindingContext) {
        //Also can I get a reference to animateImageArray here
    }
};
```

HTML

```
    <div class="customized-slider-wrapper" data-bind="yourBindingName: someData">
    <div class="customized-slider" data-bind="foreach: animateImageArray">
    <div class="individual-tile">
        <img data-bind= "attr: {src: $data}" />
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Edits:

Tried the below code in comment

```
      StopAnimation = setInterval(function () {

        _index++;
        if (_index >= imgArray.length) {
          _index = 0;
        }


         $(temp[_index]).attr('src', imgArray[_index]);


        toBeScrolledBy = slideWidth * _index;
        $(scroller).css({
          'transform': 'translateX(-' + toBeScrolledBy + 'px)'
        });

      }, 1500);
```

Now the sequence the images animates gets wrong.
The first image slides and second loads, the the animation gets back to first instead of third and it happens every time a new index is passed in the image src array.

Comment: Where are you using `someData`? Normally a binding uses the value bound to it (e.g., by using the result of `ko.unwrap(valueAccessor())`). Separately, since your array is static, there's no need for it to be observable, and no need to provide an `init` function. If the array *isn't* static, it should be the `someData` that you're not using.

Comment: Yes I am using  var data = ko.unwrap(valueAccessor()); to get the value of someData to add some information to the dom.  I am looking for a way to have a new Obeserable array in my custom binding

Comment: You'll need to provide much more detail for us to be able to usefully help you. As it stands, it makes no sense to create your own observable array in `init`.

Comment: I have created custom binding to show product tile on an ecommerce product listing page. each image of the product has 3-8 images. When the user hovers on one image I want to animate and start a side show of the images. I taught if an observable array be heloful to push images one by one and the show them in view. Does this clears the scenario?

Comment: A bit (and you should edit your question, rather than commenting with more details) -- and it tells me that the observable array should be part of the data you bind to the handler (e.g., part of `someData`), not something the handler creates out of the blue. After all, it needs the images, and those vary by product.

Comment: So if I use obserableArray part of "someData" to render the images, all the img tag will have the src value. I need to show image one by one only when user hovers a particular prodouct tile.

Comment: No. The observable array would be for the products. Each product would have an array (observable or not, depending on whether it needs to be) of its images.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From what you've described, `init` shouldn't be creating the array, and the array probably doesn't have to be observable. Instead, your observable array of products would contain objects, and each product object would have an array (probably doesn't have to be observable) of its images. Rough sketch:

```js
var vm = {
  products: ko.observableArray([
      {
          name: "Widget",
          images: [
              "https://via.placeholder.com/100/5d5/fff.png?text=Widget+1",
              "https://via.placeholder.com/100/d55/fff.png?text=Widget+2",
              "https://via.placeholder.com/100/55d/fff.png?text=Widget+3"
          ]
      },
      {
          name: "Gadget",
          images: [
              "https://via.placeholder.com/100/55d/fff.png?text=Gadget+1",
              "https://via.placeholder.com/100/5d5/fff.png?text=Gadget+2",
              "https://via.placeholder.com/100/d55/fff.png?text=Gadget+3",
              "https://via.placeholder.com/100/55d/fff.png?text=Gadget+4",
              "https://via.placeholder.com/100/5d5/fff.png?text=Gadget+5"
          ]
      },
  ])
};

ko.bindingHandlers.productSlides = {
    init: function(element, valueAccessor) {
      // Current timer handle
      var timer = 0;
      // Current slide index
      var index = 0;

      // Show first slide
      element.src = ko.unwrap(valueAccessor())[index];

      // Set up handlers
      element.addEventListener("mouseenter", startTimer);
      element.addEventListener("mouseleave", clearTimer);
  
      // Show next slide
      function nextSlide() {
          // Re-read the observable in case it's changed
          var slides = ko.unwrap(valueAccessor());
          index = (index + 1) % slides.length;
          element.src = slides[index];
      }
  
      // Start showing slides
      function startTimer() {
        if (!timer) {
            nextSlide();
            timer = setInterval(nextSlide, 1000);
        }
      }
      
      // Stop showing slides
      function clearTimer() {
          if (timer) {
              clearInterval(timer);
              timer = 0;
          }
      }
      
      // Clean up on disposal
      ko.utils.domNodeDisposal.addDisposeCallback(element, function() {
          element.removeEventListener("mouseenter", startTimer);
          element.removeEventListener("mouseleave", clearTimer);
          clearTimer();
      });
    }
};

console.log("Showing products");
ko.applyBindings(vm, document.body);

// Example of adding another product to the array later
setTimeout(function() {
    console.log("Adding third product");
    vm.products.push({
        name: "Doogle",
        images: [
            "https://via.placeholder.com/100/d55/fff.png?text=Doogle+1",
            "https://via.placeholder.com/100/5d5/fff.png?text=Doogle+2",
            "https://via.placeholder.com/100/55d/fff.png?text=Doogle+3",
            "https://via.placeholder.com/100/d55/fff.png?text=Doogle+4"
        ]
    });
}, 2000);
```

```html
<div data-bind="foreach: products">
  <img data-bind="productSlides: images">
</div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Have tried your code and facing issue, have edited my question and added my code. can u please check.

Comment: not sure why the mouse over event get unregistered after a slide change

Comment: @HarpreetSinghSaini - All due respect, questions on SO are not meant to be moving targets. I answered the question you asked, with a running demonstration. If you're having trouble applying that, then greater context was required. Adding that to the question several days later isn't ideal. Instead, keep working on it, and if you can't resolve it, post a new question with a [mcve] of the problem.

Comment: Apology!. Have created a new question and marked the above as correct. new link is below
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50703902/knockout-sliding-images-issue-with-custom-binding